# Can an ERC20 Contract receive information from BEP20 contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

are there a way for an ERC20 contract to receive information from a BEP20 smart contract ?
i would appreciate any help or links to documents or articles that give some info about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Contracts cannot interact across networks, but only within the same network.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a theory, What you are asking is cross-chain and it's not possible yet among blockchains, but smart contracts can receive data from external sources, so you need to send BEP20 contract data through API service to your ERC20 contract.

Comment: thanks, now that you mention it,
i think web3 can be one of those external sources, right ?